# "Come to my roof" - does it sound awkward and/or ambiguous to natives?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

From the allegedly official English subitles to a foreign movie.

Confidentiality hinders me from disclosing further context.

Character A addresses Character B, by saying:

> Come to my roof.

Is A simply inviting B to his house?

In my experience, this is usually the case in phrases such as *"under one's roof"* or *"a roof over one's head(s)"*, where a certain, ehm, altitude is implied.

Or is his dwelling literally situated on the roof of some other building?

As a whole, does it sound weird to natives?

Comment: What is the original sentence? Also context. Maybe they live on a roof.

Comment: @Mitch I don't speak the original language.

Comment: Yeah it sounds weird. You can say 'under my roof' as metonymy for 'in my house'. But 'to my roof' as a place can only refer to the literal roof. So using it for 'home' there sounds weird.

Comment: English Language Learners, surely.

Answer (score 1):

The only way this wouldn't be weird would be if some context were set up properly first.  Example: in the Gene Wilder, Zero Mostel film "The Producers," there is a kooky character who spends a lot of time on his roof with his pigeons and his World War II fantasies.  One could imagine him inviting another character to his roof.  In fact, I think that did take place in the film.  But even in that case, it would be more natural to say,

> Come up to the roof with me.

But subtitles are often weird.

Answer (score 0):

"Come to my roof" sounds like he's inviting her to come out onto the roof. In US sitcoms they tend to be able to get out on the roofs of their apartment buildings, e.g. [from How I Met Your Mother](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=784&bih=790&q=how+i+met+your+mother+on+roof&oq=how+i+met+your+mother+on+roof&gs_l=img.3...1721.7025.0.7463.37.17.3.16.12.0.197.1354.9j5.14.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..4.25.1216...0j0i8i30k1j0i10i24k1j0i24k1j0i30k1.1U_SA1oqMkg#spf=1). I sometimes see people in the UK on office building roofs, normally having a cigarette.

Where you talk about "under one's roof [...] where a certain, ehm, altitude is implied" it sounds like you mean *just* under the roof, which is where the bedroom normally is, implying that he might be inviting her to stay the night in his bed? If this is what you mean, then yes, it definitely does sound weird to a native British English speaker (and I'm going to guess American English speaker too).

I can't think of any direct euphemisms used in English for "stay the night in my bed" which uses "roof" or anything similar. I *might* get that impression if someone said something like:

> Why don't you come and, er, study my bedroom ceiling?

We do have other euphemisms, but no using the word "roof" or anything similar. For example:

> - Would you like to come round/in for coffee?
> - How do you like your eggs in the morning?

Comment: I had no erotic euphemisms in mind. What I meant was simply that in my experience, *roof* may refer to *house/dwelling* chiefly (or only, perhaps) when combined with prepositions such as *over* or *under*, that by definition imply a certain altitude.

Comment: Since we are on the subject of "roofs", would reading Tennessee Willams's "Cat on a hot tin roof" help us out here?

Comment: @PeterPoint - No, it would not.

Comment: @m.a.a. - I'm still not understanding what you mean by "a certain altitude is implied". Do you mean that "over a roof" and "under a roof" imply altitude?

Comment: @aparente001 What about Stellaaaaah from Street car...?!

Answer (score 0):

Context would be more helpful, but given that you're unable to provide it, the best response I can tender would be that while it sounds like it might be intimate, it might not be intended to be sexual. It would be like inviting someone to a more private area where they can talk about things unobserved.